# How to Delete Least Significant Bit in Java?

Tags: java, bit

I was given a problem in my cryptography class here:

[image]

Now, I figured instead of doing the annoying pen/paper work, I'd just write up some Java code. I know how to use Java to convert a hex string to a binary character array, but what i need to know how to do, is delete the least significant bit of those binary values.

Here is the code I've written in order to find the binary vales:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

String key = "5B5A57676A56676E"; //hexadecimal key
  char[] keyCharArray = key.toCharArray();
  for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(HexToBinary((keyCharArray[i]))+",");

      }
  }

  public static String HexToBinary(char Hex) {
      int i = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(Hex), 16);
      return String.format("%04d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(i)));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What expected output you want?

Comment: If you are stumped on how to do this you may not be ready for this course.  Hint: right-shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a `byte b` you could get the least significant bit with `boolean lsb = (b & 1) == 1;`. If lsb is true, then the lsb was 1... otherwise, it was 0. To remove the lsb, you shift `b` right by one (e.g. `b >>= 1`).

Answer (score 0):

1st - Use long/Long for 64 bit

2nd - unsetting the last bit and get the 7 remaining - you can just shift 1 (or divide by 2)

divide the key into 8 chars

shift each char by dividing by 2 (this deletes the bit)

then put the 8 chars with 7 bits together in a long (56 bits)